# Independent set poly reducible to Strongly independent set?

Tags: np-complete, np

A strongly independent set of a graph $G'$ is a subset $S$ of vertices such that the distance in $G'$ between every two distinct vertices in $S$ is larger than $2$.

It is possible to reduce an instance $\langle G, k\rangle$ of the decision version of independent set to an instance $\langle G', k\rangle$ of the decision version of strongly interdependent set by (1) replacing each edge $e=(u,v)$ of $G$ with two edges $(u, w_e)$ and $(w_e, v)$, where $w_e$ is a new vertex; and (2) connecting all the vertices $w_e$ with a clique.

In the newly created Graph $G'$, why does adding a middle node prevent us from choosing that node? Basically, how does the reduction step help us?

Solution Notes: http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~amitk/SemI-2015/tut11.pdf

Comment: Welcome to StackExchance. I added some more context to your question. Please try to post self-contained questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the integer $k$ of the (decision version of the) independent set instance $G$ you are reducing from is larger than $1$ (the case $k \le 1$ is trivial).
Let $G'$ be the graph of the corresponding instance of strongly independent set.

As it is written in your solution notes, all the additional vertices are connected to one another with a clique. If you select any of them, say $w_e$, then you cannot select any other vertex $v$ in $G'$ since the distance in $G'$ between $v$ and $w_e$ is at most $2$. This implies that the size of a maximum strongly independent set of $G'$ is $1$. Therefore, if there is a strongly independent set of $G'$ of size $k$, it must not include any vertex $w_e$.

The correctness of the reduction is then easy to see:

- If $S$ is an independent set for $G$, then $S$ is also a strongly independent set for $G'$ since all pairs vertices in $S$ are at a distance of at least $2$ in $G$ and hence they are at distance of at least $4$ in $G'$.
- If $S$ is a strongly independent set for $G'$ with $|S| \ge k$, then $S$ cannot include any vertex $w_e$, and is therefore a subset of the vertices of $G$. The distance between any two distinct vertices in $S$ is larger than $2$ in $G'$, and hence it is larger than $1$ in $G$.

Comment: Is the edge cost between a node v and we 2?

Comment: The graph is unweighted (or, if you prefer, all edges cost $1$).